# Android Studio 2.3 Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever i try to add a new Activity or Fragment i get this error.
(SDK-25.2.5)

```
 null
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.tools.idea.actions.NewAndroidComponentAction.actionPerformed(NewAndroidComponentAction.java:121)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:197)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:156)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:211)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$2(ActionMenuItem.java:304)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:905)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:284)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$300(TransactionGuardImpl.java:40)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:123)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:109)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:627)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

since this is not working,right now i'm adding java class,xml file then linking them together.is there a solution for this???

**Edit**-- Currently my project doesn't have any code(apart from default generated activity_main.xml and MainActivity.java) so there has to be an IDE error. This was caused when i tried to add new Activity to my project(by right click on project>new>Activity>EmptyActivity) and also this error is being shown in every project i opened(in the IDE error logs at the bottom right corner).
i tried invalidate and restart it didnt work
any solutions??

Comment: add some code/..

Comment: @Rotwang, I don't believe your edit is fully correct, the `android-studio` tag was necessary since the exception come from the IDE, not his project. So in fact, the duplicate won't help either since he can't debug it ;) Please add the android-version you are using

Comment: @AxelH I highly soubt that they released a faulty IDE which causes NPEs... after forcing a bazillion users to leave Eclipse!! But I could be wrong.

Comment: @Rotwang Well, the source of the exception [`com.android.tools.idea.actions.NewAndroidComponentAction.actionPerformed`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/actions/NewAndroidComponentAction.java) is a class of android studio, so a bug can happen, of course this is based on some specific case, so I bet if OP reinstall the same version, it will work fine. But hard to say since the current version as been updated.

Comment: @Rotwang Any solution???

Comment: Find the object you are using before having it instanced.

Comment: @Rotwang http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102456/android-studio-2-2-3-crashes-whenever-i-create-a-new-activity i have the same problem ....its not about the code its IDE error

Comment: @AxelH do you face the same problem while adding a new activity???

Comment: @vishalbhati No... and you seems to be one of few to have it. Please add the android-studio version (build)

Comment: @AxelH Android studio 2.3.1,Build number-"AI-162.3871768",Android sdk tools-25.2.5,Android platform version-API 25:Android 7.1.1(Nougat) revision 3,JRE-1.8.0_112,JVM:open JDK 64bit Server VM byJetBrains.btw did you check out the above link coz i have the exact same problem

Answer (score 2):

try 
- go to "File" on navigation of android studio.
- then select option "Invalidate Caches/Restart.."